# Why does this higher CP Pokemon costs less dust to upgrade than a lower CP Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why does my Vaporeon cost *less* to power up (-16%) considering that it has more CP (+16%) than my Jolteon?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look at the arc behind the Pokemon it tells you how close the Pokemon is to is **maximum CP**. The closer it is to its maximum CP the higher the stardust cost.

The Vaporeon has a higher CP than Jolteon even though it is further from its maximum CP, because the Vaporeon has a higher ***maximum*** CP than Jolteon,

Comment: That makes sense but confuses the crap out of me. My previous understanding, reinforced by reading this over and over again, is that max CP is determined by _your_ player level. Is it, then, partially determined by some _random_ attribute of the pokemon itself?

Comment: Yes, every pokemon has its own min and max possible CP, ADJUSTED by your player level. Every pokemon isnt the same CP bar. There are theories about size, move sets, etc also factoring in, but to my knowledge nothing has been proven

Comment: @8protons Apparently CP is proportional to damage per hit, not damage per second: so a fast-attacking pocket monster with a given CP is far stronger than a slow-attacking pocket monster with the same CP.  Such large differences might be part of the justification for the difference in costs...

Comment: @Yakk yes you are definitely correct, jolteon attacks faster than vaporeon whether or not this makes up for the difference I do not know

Comment: @Yakk That's good info to know. So many subtle details in this game that make a world of difference. Thank you!

Comment: @Yakk Where can you see a speed attribute?